# java.lang.NoSuchMethodException when trying to use OncePerRequestFilter

Tags: java, spring, maven, servlets, jetty

I am trying to filter incoming HTTP requests using a `OncePerRequestFilter` implementation. The bean for this is instantiated successfully, however, when running the project using `mvn jetty:run`, I am getting a `java.lang.NoSuchMethodException` with the following stack trace:

```java
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.nextscm.proxy.config.InboundLoggingFilter.<init>()
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter (ServletContextHandler.java:1362)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize (FilterHolder.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.nextscm.proxy.config.InboundLoggingFilter.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor (Class.java:2178)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler$Context.createInstance (ContextHandler.java:2655)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler$Context.createFilter (ServletContextHandler.java:1356)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize (FilterHolder.java:122)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize (ServletHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext (ServletContextHandler.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp (WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.startWebapp (JettyWebAppContext.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext (WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart (ContextHandler.java:847)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart (ServletContextHandler.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart (WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyWebAppContext.doStart (JettyWebAppContext.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart (ContextHandlerCollection.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start (ContainerLifeCycle.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start (Server.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart (ContainerLifeCycle.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart (AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart (Server.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start (AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty (AbstractJettyMojo.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.AbstractJettyMojo.execute (AbstractJettyMojo.java:343)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyRunMojo.execute (JettyRunMojo.java:169)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

I am usure what method is being referenced in this Exception as I have tried the same filter in a different project, without any additional methods, and it worked fine. What could be causing this?

Comment: `com.nextscm.proxy.config.InboundLoggingFilter` --- Hmmm... With a package name like that, it looks like a custom filter class added by you, and the **class doesn't have a no-arg constructor**, which is what the `InboundLoggingFilter.<init>()` indicates. Of course, if `InboundLoggingFilter` is supposed to be a Spring Component, the servlet container isn't supposed to call the constructor, so you likely registered the filter wrong, but since you didn't share any code for this filter or how it has been registered, we really can't help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.nextscm.proxy.config.InboundLoggingFilter.<init>()
```

This tells me, that the class InboundLoggingFilter doesn't have an empty constructor. Maybe check your implementation of the object and the documentation. Without the code however, it will be hard to help you.

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be the issue. I added a blank, empty-constructor and it seems to be wokring now